# How to create a topic in Amazon Sqs/Sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a process which publish some data(json) onto a queue on Aws-Sqs. Another process reads from this queue. All this is working fine.

Now I want to create a topic which can be listened by mutiple processes and the data is delivered to all the processes. For example Activemq and many other messaging servers have this capability to create a topic. I could not find any such thing on AWS.  The closest I could find is AWS SNS.

From what I understand AWS-SNS allows multiple clients to subscribe to a topic. But the type of subscription is either Email, Http, or Sms and so on  ... This does not really serve my purpose. I want to recieve json data in all my clients just like Sqs.

Is that achievable? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe multiple SQS into single SNS topic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html

Then it will be distributed to all of them.

The other option is to use Kinesis - https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/ but it is more difficult to set up. There you can also read from multiple clients from the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but for this to work,  I have to create mutiple queue in sqs first. Which does not make sense right. Because if I had to create multiple queues, then what is the purpose of a topic. I could publish myself to all Queues

Comment: @pvpkiran - Of course you have to create multiple SQS queues, each client needs to have unique "message storage" which it can process. The purpose is that there is central point (SNS Topic) where you can just publish messages and it will distribute it to all subscriptions (in your case SQS). When you add one more consumer, you just subscribe it to the SNS topic. In case you publish all messages by yourself, you have to do all that logic by yourself. What exactly is blocking you to create SQS for each client and subscribe them to single SNS topic?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In my opinion this is extra overhead. I need to create a topic and n number of queues  to achieve this, whereas I can achieve the same in other JMS messaging systems like activemq or rabbitmq by creating a topic. i would prefer that instead of this. There are two many moving parts here. SNS, SQS.

Comment: @pvpkiran - It would help if I know more about your use-case. SNS/SQS is quite robust for a reason, you want to use it if you want to be 100% that any published message gets to all SQS queues and it stays there until processed. Lets say you have service `X` that reads from SQS `Y` and you want to scale it up, so you scale 10 instances of service `X`. If you publish message to `Y`, do you want that all 10 instances get this message or you want just one instance of service `X` to process the message?

Answer (score 1):

amazon mq is a managed active mq service. maybe this will help with your needs?